# The query processor could not start the necessary thread resources for parallel query execution

Tags: c#, multithreading, resources, processor

What does this mean and how to solve.

I am running multi threaded c# application and this error happens when accessing database.

**The query processor could not start the necessary thread resources for parallel query execution.**

I am using "using statements" at every query so i suppose connections are getting disposed of after used.

How can i monitor what is causing this ? This is starting happening after some time like at least after 1 hour.

Windows 7 64 bit sp1 16 gb ram visual studio 2010 mssql 2008 r2 core i7 2600 @ 4.5 ghz

Comment: This is a error coming directly from your SQL server, basically meaning it is out of resources. Either your server is REALLY bussy at the moment or you have a memory leak somewhere. Use a memory profiler to see if you can detect memory leaks of native resources

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem indicates that your SQL server threads are already busy and unable to allocate any other threads to handle your request. You can also try to enable MARS (Multiple Active Result Sets) option in the connection string by setting it "MultipleActiveResultSets=true" if you're executing multiple batches.

Answer (score 12):

There is a much better answer with more discussion and details over at dba.stackexchange.com.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47237/need-to-understand-parallel-query-execution-error

Answer (score 1):

This error is from building execution plan, which is trying to parallelize complex queries. It is displayed immediately, query doesn't wait for timeout. Simple queries work as a charm.

The solution was to disable [Max degree of parallelism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181007%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) by setting it to 1. I'm not sure about performance effects of this setting, but as there are many concurrent queries on the server anyway, it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Good suggestion.  you can add this as a query hint: SELECT ...FROM ...
OPTION (MAXDOP 1);

Comment: Setting Max Degree of Parallelism from 0 to 1 worked for me.  This was on a test machine with low resources.  I wouldn't change this on a Prod Machine without checking the number of processors and determining the actual best number.

Answer (score 0):

I had the  same  issue, I was  trying to  create  Index  but I got the  error "The query processor could not start the necessary thread resources for parallel query execution", My setting of MAXDOP was  to 64, I have checked the number  of CPUs I have - they were 24, SO I set MAXDOP to  24  , the  result was the same error, But when I set to MAXDOP to  1, and executed the  Query  it worked, Not sure about the side effects  but  again I set it  back to  24 which  is equal to number  of  processors.

Hope this  helps  you !!!!